# Match inside the open and closed statement ({ and }-ish)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a file that has a list of functions and global constant variables.

```
const native func foo takes nothing returns nothing
const native func bar takes nothing returns nothing

public

   const boolean foo1 = false
   const boolean bar1 = true

   // etc etc ..... (comment line)

   const text foo68 = "Hello"
   const text bar69 = "World"

   const   int _pi = 3.14159265359
   const   int        _tau = 2*_pi

endpublic

const native func xxx takes text str returns boolean
const native func yyy takes int val returns text
native func zzz takes float val returns int

public

   // check if it works for multiple public.
   const text heh = "hello"
   const text  hehe = zero

endpublic

const native func qqq takes text str returns int
```

This is my current regex so far.

```
(?:const\s+\w+\s+)(\w+)
```

My goal here is to get the variable name inside the `public` and `endpublic`.

The result must be like this:

```
foo1
bar1
foo68
bar69
heh
hehe
```

Is it possible to match a string inside the specific open and closing tag? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to apply regex and collect all results, without having to use exec in a loop.  It's just more convenient.  Check compatibility table at bottom.  Support is relatively new.

Regex to extract from public(<->)endpublic, and then using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to apply another regex to extract const names and flatten all results into one array.
Switched from \w to [a-zA-Z0-9] to not include names with _ in them.
`...` spread operator to collect results in an array, so I can use flatMap and map on them.

```js
console.log(
[...data.matchAll(/public([\S\s]*?)endpublic/g)].flatMap(
  pub => [...pub[1].matchAll(/(?:const\s+\w+\s+)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g)].map(x=>x[1]))
)
```

```html
<script>
data = `const native func foo takes nothing returns nothing
const native func bar takes nothing returns nothing

public

   const boolean foo1 = false
   const boolean bar1 = true

   // etc etc ..... (comment line)

   const text foo68 = "Hello"
   const text bar69 = "World"

   const   int _pi = 3.14159265359
   const   int        _tau = 2*_pi

endpublic

const native func xxx takes text str returns boolean
const native func yyy takes int val returns text
native func zzz takes float val returns int

public

   // check if it works for multiple public.
   const text heh = "hello"
   const text  hehe = zero

endpublic

const native func qqq takes text str returns int`
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to match a string inside the specific open and closing tag? If yes, how?

Remember that regex is just one of many tools available to us as programmers. It can be mixed with any of those other tools. For example, one way to solve your problem is with two loops, one of which uses a regex:

1. Read each line until you find "public"
2. Read each line to parse out the variable name with your regex until you find "endpublic"